# Subsetting closure to print part of it with cat or print methods

Tags: r, oop

I'd like to create a print method, printing object class, color and 3d surface formula.
However in the object call, this surface formula needs to be as it is now, that's why `body` and `substitute` were used.
So my method correctly prints class and color, but for surface formula `cat` doesn't work and `print` gives the following output which is a `closure`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `deparse` the `body` of `f` to convert it to character:

```r
print.mychr <- function(object) {
  `%G%` <- paste0
  cat("\nObject has class: ", class(object),
        ", color: ", as.character(object$col),
        ", formula: ", deparse(body(object$f)))
}

# object call
chr1 <- chrt(c(-6, 6), 
             n = 30, 
             1+5*exp(-x^2 - y^2),
             col = 'blue')
print(chr1)
#> 
#> Object has class:  mychr , color:  blue , formula:  1 + 5 * exp(-x^2 - y^2)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use `as.list` and print third element which is the formula.

```
print.mychr <- function(object) {
  `%G%` <- paste0
  cat("\nObject has class: " %G% class(object) %G% 
        ", color: " %G% as.character(object$col) %G% "\n\n")
  print(as.list(object$f)[[3]])
}

print(chr1)
# Object has class: mychr, color: blue
# 
# 1 + 5 * exp(-x^2 - y^2)
```